# Как запретить на сервере обработку запроса, пришедшего не через ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

На странице есть возможность подгружать контент через ajax с сервера. При этом,как вы знаете, это происходит путем обращения к серверу по url, который указывается в параметрах функции ajax. Вот как распознать на сервере, что запрос пришел именно посредством ajax, а не напрямую? А то ведь в противном случае можно просто вбить в адресную строку url запроса и напрямую обратиться к серверу и получить ответ. Как это предотвратить? Запретить нужно на сервере, ведь на клиенте можно вообще js отключить...

Comment: POST запрос в адресную строку не вставишь

Comment: При вызове ajax средствами jquery и некоторых других фреймверков они добавляют к запросу заголовок X-Requested-With. Так же вы можете добавлять свои заголовки. Заголовки невозможно задать при обращении из обычного браузера через адресную строку. НО надо понимать, что помимо адресной строки браузера к вам могут обратиться как угодно (например открыв tcp соединение и сформировав http запрос самостоятельно). И в этом случае вызывающий может написать любые заголовки, которые ему нравятся и от легитимного ajax вы это не отличите

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема, если  просто вбить в адресную строку url запроса и напрямую обратиться к серверу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из фреймворка yii:

```
protected function isAjaxRequest()
    {
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']==='XMLHttpRequest';
    }
```

А вообще можно вместо GET использовать POST и на стороне сервера проверять что именно в $_POST пришли данные, тогда не получится из адресной строки браузера запустить.

Но учтите, злоумышленник если захочет, то легко эмулирирует запросы с браузера. Надо разделять приватные и публичные API.

Comment: А в laravel не подскажите подобный метод?

Comment: Гуглиться за 1.5 секунды, коммент дольше писать if(Request::ajax())

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Для того и создаётся api, чтобы можно было обратиться к нему по url хоть напрямую, хоть из кода js.